# Display an item's name as the title on the Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm working on an app that displays all the contact names in a ListView. On click, the app displays all the details of that contact in another activity.
I want to display the contact name as a title on the action bar on the other activity, so that the user can see the contact name on the action bar that he clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the other activity inside on create you can do something like:

```
String name; // Get the name from the exttra of the intent or howsoever you are getting the name
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle(name);
```

You can replace `name` with the contact name that you can pass as `extras` with the `intent` or by other ways.